# Transform rotation doesn't start from the centre of a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, compass-sass

In css we can set rotation origin point to indicate the centre of the rotate start, but the below example seems not rotate from the centre of the circle.

HTML:

```
<ul id='test' class='circle-container'>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/city/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/cats/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/food/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/animals/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/abstract/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/nature/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/city/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/cats/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/food/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/animals/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/abstract/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/nature/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/city/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/cats/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/food/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/animals/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/abstract/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/nature/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/city/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/cats/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/food/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/animals/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/abstract/'></li>
    <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/152/244/nature/'></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";

body { 
    cursor:url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

@keyframes move-right {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
                   translate(-50px)
                   rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
                   translate(-50px) 
                   rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

/**
* Mixin to put items on a circle
* [1] - Allows children to be absolutely positioned
* [2] - Allows the mixin to be used on a list
* [3] - In case box-sizing: border-box has been enabled
* [4] - Allows any type of direct children to be targeted
*/

@mixin putOnCircle(
      $nb-items, //Number of items
      $circle-size, //Parent size
      $item-size, //Item size
      $class-for-IE: false //Base class name, false means use of pseudo-selectors
   ) {
    $half-item:     $item-size / 2;
    $half-parent: $circle-size / 2;

    position: relative;               /* [1] */
    width:  $circle-size;
    height: $circle-size;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    list-style: none;                 /* [2] */ 
    @include box-sizing(content-box); /* [3] */ 

    > * {                             /* [4] */
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top:  50%; 
        left: 50%;
        width:  $item-size;
        height: $item-size;
        margin: -$half-item;

        $angle: 360 / $nb-items;
        $rot: 0;
        @for $i from 1 to $nb-items+1 {
          // If no support for IE8-

          @if $class-for-IE == false {
            &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
              @include transform(rotate(#{$rot}deg) translate($half-parent) rotate(-#{$rot}deg));
            }
          }

          // If support for IE8-  

          @else {
            &.#{$class-for-IE}#{$i} {
              // If CSS transforms are not supported
              $mt: sin($rot * pi() / 180) * $half-parent - $half-item;
              $ml: cos($rot * pi() / 180) * $half-parent - $half-item;
              margin: $mt 0 0 $ml;
            }
          }
          $rot: $rot + $angle;
        }
    }
}

.circle-container {
    @include putOnCircle(24, 2*547px, 152px, false); 
    margin: 250px auto;
    border: solid 5px tomato;
    background-color: black;

    /*.item1 {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    .item2 {
        transform: rotate(90+15deg);
    }*/
    /* a {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px tomato;
    }*/
    /*  #test {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }*/


    img {
        user-drag: none; 
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        display: block; 
        width: 100%; 
        /* border-radius: 50%; */
        /* @include  filter(grayscale(100%)); */

        /*transform-origin: center;
        transform: rotate(15deg);*/

        /*&:hover {
          @include filter(grayscale(0));
        }*/
    }
}
```

JS

```
/**
 * Apply a class to each child
 * Required for IE8-
 */
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.circle-container').children().each(function() {
  $(this).children().addClass('item'+($(this).index() + 1));
});

var angle = 90;
for(var i=1; i<=24; i++){
  $('.item'+i).rotate(angle + 15*(i-1));
}
})

var myElement = document.getElementById('test');
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

var now =0;
mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
  if (ev.type =="panleft") {
    now = now+15;
    $('.circle-container').rotate(now);
  }
  if (ev.type =="panright") {
    now = now-15;
    $('.circle-container').rotate(now);
  }
});
```

[You can check a demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/atom2ueki/pen/GJjaOe). How to fix this?

Comment: @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala There is a codepen link in my post

Comment: The transformation is off-center because the content part of the box model doesn’t match up with the visual representation of the circle. (It’s like this: `[··($$)]` — the `($$)` is what you see as your circle, the `[]` part is what the circle _actually is_. The visible circle is a bit too low.) No idea why this is, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rotation origin had no issues.  Rather, each of your `<li>`'s was being given a set width and height that were equal - creating a square.  Your image therefore overflowed the `<li>`.

[image]

A simple fix would be to re-write your mixin to take an additional parameter for the width **and height** of the images you'll be using.  Then you can center your image inside the `<li>` so it will be able to rotate without regard for the image height by `position:absolute`ing the image with a `top` attribute derived from the new `$image-height` mixin parameter:

[image]

Your new CSS rules would look like this:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: (-$item-height / 2) + ($item-width / 2);
}
```

Here is [**your example with the updated mixin**](http://codepen.io/jeremypenrod/pen/rVMXJa).

*Note: There are other ways of centering an image inside a smaller container in CSS - but this one would be very simple if you know your image's heights in advance and they are all the same dimension.*